# Parsing in Python Pandas: distinguishing inches vs. centimeters

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I don't know how to even approach this task.
I need to parse those strings with dimensions not only to convert inches to centimeters but to calculate volume into an adjacent cell.
Well, calculating volume is easy: multiply `L x W x H`.
But how to recognize dimensions in parsing inches vs. cm for correct handling? This is impossible task as it seems to me now.

Conversion is well known: `1cm = 0.393701" (and therefore 1" = 2.54cm)`

[image]

small illustration of it

```
# this is my skeleton data
#
import pandas as pd
shop_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dimentions' : ['14.23" x 14.56" x 9.89"', '2.70cm x 22.30cm x 333.40cm', '23.45" x 21.99" x 45.76"'],
    'Volume, cm3' : ['???', '???', '???'],
})
shop_df
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: You can use `regex` or `string` manipulation to distinguish cm and inches.

Comment: Thank you, Prune, I've seems given up when I came here. Thank you, ThePyGuy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine for you:

```
import pandas as pd

def volume(x):
    vol = 1
    for item in x:
        if '"' in item:
            status = "inch"
            v = item.replace('"', '')
            v = v.strip()
            vol*=float(v)
        elif 'cm' in item:
            status = "cm"
            v = item.replace('cm', '')
            v = v.strip()
            vol*=float(v)
    if status=="cm":
        return vol
    else:
        return vol*(2.54**3)


shop_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dimentions' : ['14.23" x 14.56" x 9.89"', '2.70cm x 22.30cm x 333.40cm', '23.45" x 21.99" x 45.76"'],
    'Volume, cm3' : ['???', '???', '???'],
})
for row in shop_df.iterrows():
    row[1]['Volume, cm3'] = volume(row[1]['Dimentions'].split("x"))
shop_df
```

Comment: Thank you, Cute Panda, this is absolutely great!

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies a function that creates a list of `floats` from the strings, and converts inches to cm. Then the volume is calculated with `np.prod`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
shop_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dimentions' : ['14.23" x 14.56" x 9.89"', '2.70cm x 22.30cm x 333.40cm', '23.45" x 21.99" x 45.76"'],
})

def split_data(cell):
    if '"' in cell:
        return [round(float(i)*2.54, 2) for i in cell.replace('"', '').split(' x ')]
    else:
        return [float(i) for i in cell.replace('cm', '').split(' x ')]

shop_df['Dimentions'] = shop_df['Dimentions'].apply(split_data)
shop_df['Volume'] = shop_df['Dimentions'].apply(np.prod)
```

Result:

|  | Dimentions | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [36.14, 36.98, 25.12] | 33571.8 |
| 1 | [2.7, 22.3, 333.4] | 20074 |
| 2 | [59.56, 55.85, 116.23] | 386630 |

Comment: Thank you, RJ Adriaansen, this is mind-blowing!